# Using external dependency in Java bean annotation

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Let's say I want to use opencsv. I have added the dependency in `external-dependencies.xml` asked to download the dependency by saying usemaven='true'. The jar file is downloaded and stored in the lib folder of the extension

[image]

Now if I want to use this dependency to generate Java bean which contains annotation example.

```
<bean class="com.something.dto.IndirectSaleData">
    <import type="com.opencsv.bean.CsvBindByName"/>
    <property name="firstName" type="java.lang.String">
        <annotations>@CsvBindByName(column = "first_name", required = true)</annotations>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Why is it not able to resolve the dependency?

[image]

On the other hand if I directly create the Java Class it works totally fine example-

```
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvBindByName;
public class Data {

    @CsvBindByName(column = "first_name", required = true)
    private String name;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From question itself seems like the problem is not in the library dependency, but in bean XML definition instead.
Also it's not readable to define beans with annotations like that. Better to add it as Java class directly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to plug in the dependency in the build class path. We can use `buildcallbacks.xml` for this. What I did is I moved the external dependency to `platform/core/lib` as I want it to be available during generation of model classes.

code snippets:

```
<macrodef name="yourExtensionName_before_build">
    <sequential>
        <echo message="Copy external jar to platform core"/>
        <!-- Copy the jar from your extension lib folder to platform core -->
        <copy file="${ext.yourExtensionName.path}/lib/your-dependency.jar"
              todir="${platformhome}/ext/core/lib" failonerror="true"/>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Comment: For me the _before_build did not work. I had to use _after_clean